# Front wheels toed in at the top, king-pin wear

Tags: meaning

This paragraph has a coupled of things I don't understand:

> A large number of native-owned cars have their front wheels **toed in at
>   the top**. This is apparently **king-pin wear**, since their owners never
>   give them any attention beyond gas, oil and water, so long as they
>   will run.

1. What does it mean for the front wheels to be *toed in at the top*?
2. What does *king-pin wear* mean?

Comment: http://www.ozebiz.com.au/racetech/theory/align.html  Also look up automotive steering king-pin. -- wear and tear of the king-pin.

Comment: A "king pin", on older style cars and many trucks, is the main hinge pin for the front wheel steering.  Terms like "toe-in" unfortunately have several different interpretations, depending on who is talking.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it means that the writer doesn't know much about auto mechanics :-)  Toe-in is when the front of the wheels are closer together than the back.  What is meant here appears to be camber: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camber_angle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A king-pin is a component of a beam suspension. (used frequently in heavy duty trucks)  It is the pin that connects various components at the hub.

If the wheel is "toed in at the top" the wheel is farther in at the top than the bottom.  Typically if you hear of a modern car with "toe in," it means the front of the tire is farther in than the back.

"King-pin wear" would mean that the pin was wearing and getting lose.  Extra "toe in at the top" would indicate that the pin was no longer holding all of the suspension parts in their correct positions.